# Is there a MATLAB editor/plugin/version with better code completion?

Tags: matlab, intellisense, code-completion

Comparing Visual Studio code completion with [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB) R2008b 7.7 there are a few important features missing in the last one:

1. Local variables completion
2. Function, for, if auto ENDing

But Visual Studio doesn't support MATLAB code. Is there any MATLAB plugin, editor or version with a better code completion?

Comment: It doesn't matter if it is for Visual Studio or Matlab or if it is a another text editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Windows, Notepad++ allows code completion of functions and words.

Comment: Do you have any links to a MATLAB API file?

Comment: @Jacob - as far as I can see, the latest notepad++ binaries include matlab syntax support.

Comment: MATLAB syntax support in Notepad++ is pretty abysmal. It doesn't support %% cells, for one thing, and is just generally inferior to the MATLAB editor.

Comment: @jjparker Thanks for pointing out the lack of cell support in Notepad++. I rarely (never) use Matlab cells, so it's npt something I've tested in there

Answer (score 10):

You could always take a look at [MATLAB-Emacs integration](http://blogs.mathworks.com/desktop/2009/09/14/matlab-emacs-integration-is-back/) (also deals with Vim in the article).

Also, while we're at the subject:
[Editing MATLAB files with Vim](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21798)
[Evaluate selected text from Vim in Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/245617)

Answer (score 1):

With the R2010a release of MATLAB, the Editor's tab completion now includes [local variables](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_env/brqxeeu-23.html#brqxeeu-41).