# Running just the matlab editor

Tags: editor, matlab

Is there a way to just run the matlab (7.9.0) editor and not the rest of the "desktop" on linux?

Comment: You may be interested in the editor alternatives listed in these others questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83190/looking-for-an-alternative-matlab-editor, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467813/is-there-a-matlab-editor-plugin-version-with-better-code-completion

Answer (score 5):

This can't be done directly, because the editor stopped being a stand-alone executable many releases ago. It is now launched as a separate Java window from the Matlab desktop. However, you could try hiding the desktop once the editor is displayed, using the following simple code snippet:

```
com.mathworks.mde.desk.MLDesktop.getInstance.getMainFrame.hide  % to hide desktop
com.mathworks.mde.desk.MLDesktop.getInstance.getMainFrame.show  % to show desktop
```

Note that if your editor is docked to the desktop, it will be hidden together with the desktop, so be careful...

Answer (score 3):

No, this is no longer possible since [r2007a](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/rn/bq1zi27-1.html#bq4h5rd-1).

You can get Matlab syntax highlighting for emacs and vi, though.

Comment: +1 - Great answer! Also, I use Notepad++ for the highlighting on Windows

Answer (score 3):

On my windows machine, I can start MATLAB with the `-nodesktop` option, then once in the command prompt, I start only the editor with `edit`.

Im not sure if this is different in terms of memory space used, but this way you only get the editor and the command prompt (no auto-completion though)

Answer (score 0):

You can add Matlab syntax highlighting to Kate [via a plugin](http://search.cpan.org/~szabgab/Syntax-Highlight-Engine-Kate-0.06/lib/Syntax/Highlight/Engine/Kate/Matlab.pm).  I don't know about gedit, but there's probably an addon for that as well.